# C# MVC Project Architecture for multiple subdomain

Tags: c#, subdomain, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am trying to build a new MVC Project. The thought is I will have a parent domain, and I will be hosting multiple sub products at different sub domains.

[ For Users it will be totally different products.. like: life.insurance.com and general.insurance.com].. and it is also possible that two different teams work on these two child products and they may have different Release Date.

Main thing is, I want to change my Web Project Layer. The Domain Layer, DAL Layer, etc will be common. I was searching for some best Industry Practices in MVC.

Thoughts that I have in Mind:

1. Create different MVC Areas in Web Project. But what if I want to send product A code to Production but not the Product 2 Code. ***[How to Resolve this]***
2. Use different Web Projects and change the dll only at Production.

Please suggest. or any New way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Use different Web Project for different product and class library for business rule. Common business rule should go in one class library and project specific business rule should go in different class library.

Answer (score 0):

Under Main Project solution, Create Separate MVC projects for each of the subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple projects for DAL, DomainLayer, Crosscutting, DTOs, UI, Test etc. You can extend it as much as you need and you can find many sample architectures in different complexities. Considering your specific questions, you can route requests using Area as you pointed. In addition, you can implement Areas in different projects which enable you extend your solution without modifying the web project. However; you need to take into consideration that once you add DLL references to your web project, you cannot directly change specific DLLs without rebuilding the whole web project. In order to achive that, you need to resolve your plugin assemblies in runtime. So, you can use Assembly.Load that will help you load specific DLLs anytime you wish.